# What is the best way to organize OpenAPI code generated clients?

Tags: openapi

OpenAPI client code generation allows for 2 use-cases in the case of in-house clients:

1. service clients:
   Generated client code is tied to a the openAPI of a specific service, covers all the API of that service, and is controlled and maintained (as much as needed for a generated code) by the same developers that handle the service code, and there are no code duplications
2. usage dependant clients:
   Each use case will generate his own client, based on the endpoints in use for that particular use-case. You get smaller clients, thatcover only the endpoints that are in use - the people who are responsible for maintaining those clients are the same people responsible for the specific use-case, and there can be code duplication between different generated clients

If i compare the 2 options i see the following:

```
+-----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------+
| Criteria              | service based clients        | use-case based clients |
+-----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------+
| Ownership             | Service maintainers          | use-case maintainers   |
| Code duplication      | No duplication               | a lot of duplications  |
| Clients sependancy    | Dependancy exists            | No dependancy          |
| Client code stability | When upgrading client        | When updating client   |
| Base url              | Single per client            | Per endpoint (group)   |
| Language/Tech Stack   | Depends on service           | Depends on client      |
+-----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------+
```

In the case of an outside use of the API those same scenarios also exists: if we release OpenAPI specification only - we are supporting use-case based clients, and if we release a client library - we are supporting service based clients (they are not mutually exclusive)

In my case i am talking about an in-house usage, and that means that the knowledge of the division between services is a common knowledge between the service providers and the service users

Does anyone have good arguments that i have missed regarding any of those 2 use-cases - and a 3rd use-case i have missed?

Right now i am leaning towards a use-case based clients for in-house use, since it will allow us to treat this generated code as a completely transparent layer, leaving only the OpenAPI specs as the layer of communication between teams